# Using annotate() on top of django filters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Is it possible to use annotate on top of Django filters? I'm not referring to the filter() in the django documentation but django-filters.

Something like this gave me an attributeerror to say that the filter does not have the attribute annotate.

Please let me know if you require other codes

views.py

```
post = postFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude((Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all()) | Q(author = request.user))).order_by('date_updated')).annotate(user_has_interest=Case(When(interest__user=request.user, then=Value(True)), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-filter` instance `postFilter` does not have any attribute named annotate, but the queryset does have it. You can either add in queryset argument like this:

```
post = postFilter(
    request.GET,
    queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude(
            Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all() |
            Q(author = request.user)
        ).order_by('date_updated').annotate(
            user_has_interest=Case(
                When(interest__user=request.user, then=Value(True)),
                default=False, output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Or you can add it later to filter's [**`qs`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html?highlight=qs#filtering-the-primary-qs) attribute. For example:

```
post = postFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude((Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all()) | Q(author = request.user))).order_by('date_updated'))

post_qs = post.qs.annotate(user_has_interest=Case(When(interest__user=request.user, then=Value(True)), default=False, output_field=BooleanField()))
```